# kraken2 output to OTU table

Tags: microbial-genomics

I ran kraken2 on a 16s rRNA sample. I get two kinds of output, one like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uz_Ms9KBhJehIu9shzCFmbFoYy_albnY/view?usp=sharing)
and the other one like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19vpgWaelvGsnWb7oET5y4SysKb6n4_GV/view?usp=sharing). So I have many files like this for each sample of my control and test group.

How do I generate OTU table out of these outputs for phyloseq usage? Do I parse the taxa ID column of any of these and generate a frequency table of each taxa in sample to generate OTU?

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: able to fix it ..issue resolved

Comment: Can you share how you fixed this please? Having the same learning curve!

Comment: Can you please add your fix / resolution as a separate answer (and accept it)? This is appearing in the question list as unanswered.

Comment: okay may be i will close the question..